# Illustrator Custom Art Brush Stroke Inverted Colour

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

I'm using a custom art brush I made with the pen tool, and the stroke seems to have a different colour than the fill and I can't figure out how to get the stroke colour to match the colour that is shown when used.

[image: Art Brush Settings]

[image: Example of Inverted Colour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Color variations in the brush would be caused by the **Hue Shift** setting in the brush options:

[image]

Hue Shift does some color "voodoo" I can't really explain... it combines the stroke color (brush color) with underlying colors to come up with an overall "shift" between the two. I don't know the exact math or logic behind it. However, I have always found "hue Shift" to be terribly unpredictable in most instances. It's okay if working on a fairly monochromatic area and toying with it to see *how* things shift (then adjust).

If you want the color to change with the applied stroke color.. set it to **Tints** or **Tints and Shades**, the latter is my personal preference.

If you want the brush to remain the color it was created at.. set that option to **None**.